# Jsp Editable Datagrid

Tags: java, jsp, datagrid

I have to build a datagrid.The grid should be editable and values should be passed .I am new to JSP .Can anyone tell me the step by step procedure of creating a editable datagrid in jsp without connecting to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/

You can simply apply it to an html table (create it in the jsp), and it will make it client-side editable.

Here's an example of how to do it:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/wiki/HTMLSource